# javascript firing event when textbox changes programmatically

Tags: javascript, events, textbox, client, onchange

I have an application in which server is sending data to client that I need to program. Each string of data is sent to a unique text box. I want to catch this data and format it before displaying depending on state of independent selectable list. I cannot fire an event using onchange as it works only for user's input. Is there an easy way of doing that? I couldn't find one straight solution for this.

```
<input class="dios" id="diosinput" type="text" value="" data-ref="#source" data-path="/abc/0/input" />


<select class="widthed"> 
<option>Hex</option> 
<option>Binary</option> 
</select>
//my function 

function decToHex(d)
{
var displayHex = d.toString(16);

if(displayHex.length<2) displayHex = '0'+ displayHex;

return '0x'+ displayHex.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Does the server return a prefilled HTML textbox?

Comment: no, it is just sending string of information to box with chosen id

Comment: Then why not intercept that and do your thing with it before it is processed?

Comment: hmmm... I dont know how to catch this data before it reaches the text box. Server is walking through all boxes and sends them string of info basing on their id. If i could catch it it would be great, but the easiest option i see is to just receive it and than try to work on it. Do you have other solution?

Comment: There's no mechanism that allows a server to send a browser some "string of information" directed at a text input on a page. There must be some code in your application already that's handling this, and that's where you need to make your changes.

Comment: ok, there is one, right. The problem is that this part of code needs to stay generic. I'm not allowed to change it there and create additional code for each of my 100 textboxes. That's why i need to work with received information rather than change information itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fireEvent(element,event) {
  if (document.createEventObject) {
    // dispatch for IE
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
  } else {
    // dispatch for others
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
}

fireEvent(document.getElementById('InsertIdOfYourInput'), 'change');
```

Comment: ok, but how do I bind it with textbox and selectable list and my function? I updated my post with code

Answer (score 0):

There are only two way to change a text box from the server:

1. When the browser loads the whole page
2. When the browser sends an AJAX request to the server and replaces the text in the input element

There is no way for a web server to "send data to a text box". You probably mean something else but you're missing the right words to express it.

What I can see from the source is `data-ref` and `data-path`. This suggests that AJAX is used to fetch a new value from the server and put it into the DOM.

To change this, look at the whole source code of the page (including all JavaScript code) and look for `path` or `data-path` or `data('path')` or `data("path")`

If you find the place where the request is made, you will know where to add your own callback.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being precise. I know where this part you are talking about is. The problem is that I cannot interfere with the stream of data there. What i have to do is to format data in the right way after i receive it with my text box... Can it be done?

Comment: No event is fired when JavaScript changes part of the DOM, so you must change the original callback. The problem is that you don't know how to do this but we can help. Post the callback code and we tell you how to patch it from the outside (ie. without changing the original source code).

Answer (score -1):

```
 function Evaluate() {
        var q1 = document.getElementById("<%=txtqty.ClientID %>").value
}

<asp:TextBox ID="txtqty" runat="server" CssClass="txtclass"  Width="40px" ValidationGroup="AddLoan" onchange="return Evaluate();" >
```